# how to use gitblit

Tags: git, version-control, gitblit

[Gitblit](http://gitblit.com/) looks pretty interessting to run a GIT server, so I installed it (which is realy easy).

But now I'm having some problems to get my way around the tool. Its easy to create repos, but after that, I'm stuck - after creation I was not able to "dive" into the repo itself e.g. like on this screenshot: http://gitblit.com/screenshots/03.png

I also noticed that in my installation I have only the first three menu items on top ('repositories', 'users' and 'federation') - which seems logical, as they should appear when "diving" into a repo e.g. 'branches', 'tags' and 'tree'.

I think it is not a security issue, as I disabled security and I also was able to greate a repo. 
I'm just missing a link or a button to select a reo and see all the infos about it. There is only a 'edit' link, but that brings me back to the same screen as when creating a repo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get an answer on this one, I posted it also on the issue list of Gitblit...

http://code.google.com/p/gitblit/issues/detail?id=31

The reason for not being able to "dive" into the repo was, that there is no empty repo page when there is nothing pushed to the repo yet.

Out of this request, an empty repo page will be added in a future release of gitblit.